# What is meant by cycle?

Tags: inspeqtor

What does cycle mean at INQ Configuration:

```
check service memcached
  if memory:rss > 1200m for 4 cycles then alert
  if cpu:user > 40% for 2 cycles then restart
```

Any idea?

**EDIT**
This is related to Inspeqtor at https://github.com/mperham/inspeqtor

Answer (score 0):

Refers to monitoring cycle. What other explanation are you looking for?

Comment: Can you suggest a link please? I could not find docs about it, also, kindly see my edit above